# Partial view not working properly

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing MVC 3 application and using razor syntax.

In this application I am giving commenting facility.

I have added the Comment link in every Div. . When user click on that comment link, it loads the partial view which contains group of controls for Adding comments.

I am using list to disply records, and when user click on comment button I use the partial view to load comment control.

Now the problem is I can add comment only for first record I cant add comment on other records...

What the problem ?

Please check below image...

[image]

Here is the code which is in partial view which add comment in DB and again fetches latest comment back to view to display It.

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


 <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#AddCommentButton').click(function () 

        {
        var comment1 = $('#Comment').val();
        if (comment1 == '') {
            alert('Please enter a comment');
            return;
        }


            $.ajax({

                type: 'post',
                url: '/Comment/SaveComments',
                dataType: 'json',


                data:
                { 

                 'comments' : $('#Comment').val(), 
                 'EType' : @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.EType)), 
                  'EId' : @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.EId))

                },
                success: function (data) {


                                   $("p.p12").append('<button type="button" id=' + data.Id  + ' class="deleteComment2">Delete</button></div>')



                }

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I use below code, when i clicked on the delete button...

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.deleteComment').live('click', function () {
        alert('Clicked');
    });

</script>
```

Now , the summary of a problem is I append div and in that div I add a button and I am trying to get click event of that button but I cant get that event.

Can anyone please give the simple code for handling of button's click event when button get added runtime in the Div tag.

***Here is the update code for Darin Dimitrov***

```
@model  IEnumerable<CRMEntities.Comment>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>


 <!DOCTYPE html>


<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).on('click', '.deleteComment', function() 
   {
    alert('comment deleted');    
});


$(document).ready(function () {
alert("Doc loaded");

});
​

</script>




<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#AddCommentButton').click(function () {

            $('#comments22').append('<input type="button" class="deleteComment" value="Delete" /><br/>');
            $('#comments22').append('<input type="button" class="deleteComment" value="Delete" /><br/>');
            $('#comments22').append('<input type="button" class="deleteComment" value="Delete" /><br/>');
            $('#comments22').append('<input type="button" class="deleteComment" value="Delete" /><br/>');
        });
    });
</script>




<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".ShowComments").click(function () {
            $(".ParentBlock").slideToggle("slow");

        });
    });
</script>



</head>
<body>

@{





     <div class="ParentBlock">



    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="OwnerClass" id="OwnerName">


         <span class="EmpName"> @Html.ActionLink(item.Owner.FullName, "Details", "EMployee", new { id = item.OwnerId }, new { @style = "color:#1A6690;" })</span>

           @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.CommentDateTime)

          <span class="EmpName"><button type="button" id = "@item.Id" class="deleteComment">Delete</button></span>



          <span class="EmpName"> @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Comment", new { id = item.Id }, new { @style = "color:#1A6690;" })</span>


        <p class="CommentP">
           @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.CommentText)
        </p>

        <br />
            <a class="Delete222" style="cursor:move;display:none;">DeleteNew</a>
        <br />

        </div>


    }


     <p class="p12">

      </p>



</div>

      <p id="ClassPara" class="ShowComments" onclick="chkToggle()">Show All Comments</p>

}



   @Html.TextArea("Comment", "", 5, 80, "asdsd")


    <input type="button" value="Add Comment" id="AddCommentButton"/>                         
    <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="clearText()"/>                    

    <br />

    <div id="comments22">
    <input type="button" class="deleteComment" value="Delete" /><br/>
    <input type="button" class="deleteComment" value="Delete" /><br/>    
    <input type="button" class="deleteComment" value="Delete" /><br/>


</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide any code behind ?

Comment: Please provide some more details.

Comment: I have upladted my question, please check the code section now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have subscribed to the click event of  `#AddCommentButton`. But as you know ids must be unique in the whole DOM. You can only have 1 element with `id="AddCommentButton"`. So you should use a class selector for your `Add Comment` button:

```
$('.addComment').click(...);
```

and your button:

```
<input type="button" value="Add Comment" class="addComment" />
```

Also I hope you have taken note of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12561510/29407). Apparently you haven't as I still see you hardcoding urls in your view instead of using helpers.

Comment: Its not the issue abt adding the comment, its abt deleting the comment. newly added button in appended Div tag is not working...

Comment: sorry Darin Dimitrov, Actually I have messed up with my code...I have follow your tips...bit thats in another copy... Currently I just want to get the click event of the newly added button...

Comment: In order to get the click event of newly added buttons working you need to use `.on()` or `.delegate()` or `.live()`. Also in your question you are saying that you have problems with adding comment. You even provided a screenshot in which you explain that it works only for the first comment but not for subsequent comments. The reason for this as I explained in my answer is because you cannot have multiple buttons with the same id and you need to use a class selector. Also if those Add Comment buttons are added later to the DOM you should use .on to subscribe to their click handler.

Comment: exactly, but `.on()` `.live()` and `.delegate()` is not working in my code. is that issue related to script. ? I am updating my question, where you can see the ref. of the scripts which I have used.

Comment: I repeat it for the last time: you need to use `.on()`.

Comment: ya,I tried it, I have used all the three types... but its not working at all... Is there script ref. issue ?

Comment: I have no idea. Look at FireBug to identify if you have some issues with javascript. Verify if the script is correctly included in the Network tab and that you don't have some 404 errors. Then verify that you don't have any javascript errors. Here's a fully working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bfauY/1/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17094/discussion-between-user1668543-and-darin-dimitrov)

Comment: Could you send me your project exhibiting the problem? I will take a look at it and tell you what's wrong.

Comment: I have merged my code with your code...Still not working...Please check my updated question...

Comment: You seem to have included jquery multiple times. You have many script inclusions that are just wrong. I have cleaned the mess for you here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565644/handling-click-event-of-button-which-added-in-div-tag-runtime/12577748#12577748

Comment: Thanks a lot Darin Dimitrov, your code works... I really appreciate your efforts that you take to solve my problem. Your support will always motivate the beginners like me to solve problems...Thanks again... :)

Comment: @user1668543, glad I could help. Now you still have a couple of pending questions on this same topic that are waiting to be closed.

Comment: @ Darin Dimitrov, I am trying to close the question but I not getting any close options due to I have low reputation ?  should I flag it for modrator ?

Comment: @user1668543, by closing the question I meant `accepting an answer`. Also on this thread you have accepted an answer that doesn't really has anything to do with your problem because it suggest you using the `.click()` event handler for the delete button but this is wrong because those buttons are added dynamically and you should use the `.on()` function. In my answer I provided you with the correct source code. But anyway.

Comment: Hello Darin Dimitrov, I have put this question but I didnt get answer yet. cna you please look into it ?  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595102/runtime-added-partial-view-in-list-view-not-working-properly)

Answer (score 1):

hi you can get your delete event like this it's below

```
 $(".lnkDelete").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var targeturl = $(this).attr("href");

 and you can pass that targert url to your delete button like this 

window.location.href = targeturl;
```

i think this will help you....